# Compute an aerodynamic shape

Tags: aerodynamics

I'm interested in building a Fairing for a recumbent bicycle.

A fairing is just a rigid curved surface (usually plastic or fiberglass) that surrounds the bike in order to reduce wind drag. Apparently it can increase your speed dramatically (as much as 300% with zero wind relative to the ground).

Questions of building the thing aside (which looks feasible actually), how can I compute the "most" aerodynamic surfaces to enclose a given space?

In other words, if I have a given three dimensional "blob" (my body's range on motion + the bike itself) and a given direction of motion, what formulae and/or software can I use to give me some highly-aerodynamic shapes that are just slightly larger than the blob?